# Multiple URL Redirect to HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, htaccess

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't quite work it out.

My Magento website has several (duplicate) URL's:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/index.php/  
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/index.php
```

I want them all linking to the https version of example.com

I tried adding the following in my htaccess root file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work (it means I can no longer access my www.example.com/admin site). Any ideas? I'm sure this must be a common thing with Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to change anything in `.htaccess` file. Please revert back to it's original.

Go to `system > configuration > web > secure` and set your secure url (with https). **Make sure you add "`/`" at the end of your url (https://www.example.com/index.php/)**.

Then set **Use Secure URLs in Frontend** to **Yes**

Clean your cache and you are done.

If you want to remove `index.php` from your site, then [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938860/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-the-url-in-magento#answer-16939149).

Comment: If you want all pages to use `https`  only, you should also change the base url in the "unsecure" section. "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" only applies to login and checkout.

Comment: Thanks @fschmengler for pointing that too. Although, without setting secure url in "unsecure" section, it should work.